# Change $102 \to 201$

Tags: mathematics, number-theory

Suppose you start with the number $102$ and, at each step, you are allowed to double the number, add the number's digits, multiply its digits, or add 1. Your goal is to go from $102$ to $201$ in as few steps as possible. Of course, you could add $1$ $99$ times, but... where's the fun in that? Here is my best attempt:

> $102 \to 3 \to 6 \to 12 \to 24 \to 25 \to 50 \to 100 \to 200 \to 201$

Comment: Your attempt is indeed the least amount of steps possible.

Comment: Have you proven it mathematically?

Comment: I've proven it by letting my computer calculate all the possible paths with 9 or less steps from 102 and it showed that there were no possible paths with 8 or less steps.

Comment: Nice... that's pretty good. Were there any other paths with $9$ steps?

Comment: @Frpzzd Yes, The other two paths result in the same answer of 9, with the beginning being multiply by two, then add the digits, being 102 -> 204 -> 6... or once again multiply to make 102 -> 204 -> 408 -> 12 ...

Comment: ‮ ‮Just add a right to left character in front of the 102 and it'll become 201 in a jiffy.  D:

Comment: .ysae oot ti ekam dluow tahT! !aH !aH trAlufituaeBylpmiS@

Comment: ‮ ‮​‮@Frpzzd But notice my text is on the right of my name.  (-:

Comment: .noitatuper 265,53 htiw dog gnikaerf a er'ouY. taht od ot woh wonk uoy esruoc fO *...hgiS*

Comment: Nah, just use [this magic trick](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131802/how-do-some-people-add-stuff-to-their-right-of-the-user-name-in-comments/131803#131803).  :D

Comment: Just don't use excessively or you will get in trouble.  (gives the serious look)

Comment: ‮(Nods obediently)

Comment: I can do it in zero mathematical steps by turning my calculator upside-down....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is:

> No - there is not a shorter path

but

> there are alternate paths. You can start the sequence with 102 doubled is 204 summed is 6...

or

> Start with 102 doubled is 204 doubled is 408 summed is 12...

Answer (score 12):

Your attempt uses the least amount of steps possible. I have written a computer program that calculates the shortest possible paths between $102$ and $201$ and it has found four with nine steps. I believe that these are all of them:

> \begin{align*}102 \to 3 \to 6 \to 12 \to 24 \to 25 \to 50 \to 100 \to 200 \to 201\end{align*} \begin{align*} 102 \to 204 \to 6 \to 12 \to 24 \to 25 \to 50 \to 100 \to 200 \to 201 \end{align*} \begin{align*} 102 \to 204 \to 408 \to 12 \to 24 \to 25 \to 50 \to 100 \to 200 \to 201 \end{align*} \begin{align*} 102 \to 204 \to 408 \to 816 \to 48 \to 49 \to 50 \to 100 \to 200 \to 201 \end{align*}

I find the last one the most interesting.

Comment: That last one is interesting... the only one that uses the product of the digits.

Comment: @Pjotr5 can you share the logic of the computer program you made? It interests me.

Comment: Glad you posted your answer as well. I missed that last one.

Comment: @prog_SAHIL The program was nothing clever, just naive brute-force. It took a list of all paths of length $n$ and outputted all paths of length $n+1$. So for $\{\{102\}\}$ it would output $$\{\{102, 204\}, \{102, 3\}, \{102, 0\}, \{102, 103\}\}.$$ Then at each step it would check if $201$ was already reached. Because I knew it would terminate after at most $9$ iterations, I knew brute-force would be plenty fast enough.

Comment: @Pjotr5 Thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: @Pjotr5 you may want to edit your answer to include your brief explanation of your program.

Comment: What about 102 - 103 - 206 - 12 - 24 - 25 - 50 - 100 - 200 - 201?

Comment: @loopywalt I understand you multiply 2x6 = 12, but you cannot ignore the 0 imho.

Comment: @FlorianF ah, good point. Thanks.